# Who manages the nodes in an AKS cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

I started using the AKS service with 3 nodes setup. As I was curious I peeked at the provisioned VMs which are used as nodes. I noticed I can get root on these and that there need to be some updates installed. As I couldn't find anything in the docs, my question is: Who is in charge of managing the AKS nodes (vms).

Do I have to do this myself or what is the idea here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You. Microsoft is only patching the management nodes.

Comment: @evilSnobu thx for the reply. Do you have a source for this information. Also I'm confused because I can upgrade the kubernetes software of the nodes via the a cli.

Comment: There is support for OS updates built into ScalabilitySets. I think it's Preview now, but perhaps AKS could be made to take advantage of ScaleSets and get this feature. For now maybe you are completely on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Azure automatically applies security patches to the nodes in your cluster on a nightly schedule. However, you are responsible for ensuring that nodes are rebooted as required.
You have several options for performing node reboots:

1. Manually, through the Azure portal or the Azure CLI.
2. By upgrading your AKS cluster. Cluster upgrades automatically cordon
   and drain nodes, then bring them back up with the latest Ubuntu
   image. Update the OS image on your nodes without changing Kubernetes
   versions by specifying the current cluster version in az aks
   upgrade.
3. Using Kured, an open-source reboot daemon for Kubernetes.
   Kured runs as a DaemonSet and monitors each node for the presence of
   a file indicating that a reboot is required. It then manages OS
   reboots across the cluster, following the same cordon and drain
   process described earlier.